# Create item with Person or Group column with HTTP request in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, person-or-group

I am struggling with creating a new list item with Person or Group column via HTTP request in Power Automate while using claims of the users. I can't get the syntax to work.

I was able to create workaround updating (not creating) item that works, but with this I need to create empty item before my workaround below.

Any idea how to make it works for create item HTTP Request?

My current HTTP request:

```
Method: POST
    
Uri: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTTITLE')/items(123)/validateUpdateListItem

Headers: <none>
Body:
{
    "formValues": [{
        "FieldName": "AssignedToMultiSelect",
        "FieldValue": "[{'Key':'user_claims'}]"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using "create item" action or only `/items` endpoint to create a list item instead of `/validateUpdateListItem`?

Comment: That's the point I couldn't find the working syntax of HTTP Request with just `/items`. "Create item" is hard to move between tenants and also I couldn't set alternative name in hyperlink column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add items use `AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath` instead of `ValidateUpdateListItem`.

You should use the following formats for the `FieldValue` property for People or Group fields. The `Key` property value should be `'i:0#.f|membership|'` plus the user's email address.

With single select: `"FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|adelev@contoso.com'}]"`

With multiple select: `"FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|adelev@contoso.com'},{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|alexw@contoso.com'}]"`

Comment: that's what I am using now, but I cannot manage to make working HTTP Request to CREATE item, I am missing some headers settings or body syntax idk.

Comment: To add an item use `AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath` instead of `ValidateUpdateListItem`. The body format for the request is similar. Here's an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#create-list-item-in-a-folder

Comment: its working with `/GetByTitle('Test')/AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath` ! Thank you, I don't know why I did not found this documentation earlier! post it in the answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help. I updated my answer to include the information from my comment above.